# Error with predict and glm.predict in R

Tags: r, types, glm, predict

**The Problem**

I trained a linear regression in R to predict `this.target` from `city`, variables in data frame `data`. This trainig is done on a subset of the data, which is specified by `train.index`.

```
model = glm('data[, this.target] ~ data$city', data = data, subset = train.index)
```

I am trying to test this model on the held out data, which is specified by `test.index`.

```
predictions = predict(model, data[test.index, ])
```

For whatever reason, this second step creates an error and a warning.

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev =
object$xlevels) : invalid type (NULL) for variable 'data$city' In addition:
Warning message: 'newdata' had 22313 rows but variables found have 0 rows
```

**My Analysis**

`data$city` is a factor of 4 levels, but it seems like R reads it as an "invalid type (NULL)" even though none of the observations in this variable are NULL.

Moreover, it seems like R reads the rows but not the columns of the training set correctly. `dim(data[test.index, ])` yields a vector with 22313 and 12.

Comment: Your formula in `glm` is totally wrong. Your formulas should never include subsetting operations like `[` or `$`. Just the variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to joran's comment, I was able to find the solution to my problem. joran pointed out that formulas should not include subsetting operations.

As it turns out, this subsetting was allowing model fitting to proceed as normal, but it caused model predicting to balk with the error and warning described above. By removing subsetting from my formula definition, both model fitting and predicting ran without problem.

Comment: i have the same problem, can you tell me how to solve subsetting operations problem?

Comment: In the above example, instead of `model = glm('data[, this.target] ~ data$city', data = data, subset = train.index)` I did `model = glm('target ~ city', data = data, subset = train.index)`.

Answer (score -1):

This solution is for this error but not for the main question cause it is difficult to follow .

The solution is making a variable let's say `x`; `x=as.data.frame(testset)` and pass it to predict as

```
classifier = glm(formula = Survived ~ .,
                 family = binomial,
                 data = training_set)
x = as.data.frame(test_set)
prob_pred = predict(classifier, type = 'response', newdata =x)
y_pred = ifelse(prob_pred > 0.5, 1, 0)
```

## Predicting the Test set results

In glm or rpart (library for classification based on decision tree), the test set should be data frame and sometimes the pre-processing steps change your data type (the data you want to predict) should be data frame, if it is not, the
error

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action,
>   xlev = object$xlevels): 'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix
>   or an array

will appear.